# Get friends attending to an event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I searched in the documentation and in the web and didn't find anything about this.

So, when you go to an event page on facebook the list of people who are attending to the event seems to be ordered putting your friends in first place. I want to do that but I can't figure out how.

If I make:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<event_id>/attending
```

I get all people who are attending and it seems it is ordered by when the person clicked on 'attending'.

If I make:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/<event_id>/attending/<user_id>/friends
```

I get all friends of the user regardless if they are attending to the event or not.

I tried a lot of connections using Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) like getting the friends of the user and then trying to match them with that event, but could'nt find the solution.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more suited to an FQL query. Hold on, I'll post a sample query as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use FQL in this case. More suited to this type of nested question.

```
select uid, rsvp_status from event_member where eid = <EVENT_ID> and uid IN (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

That will return all friends of the person logged in who are attending the event you specify.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answear Colm. This solves the problem of course, but you know for sure that there is not a way to do it by the Graph API? I ask because I have been using the graph since the begining and I may have to alter 2 or 3 big functions of my code =p

Comment: Well you can call FQL using the Graph API if that's any help? - `HTTP://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=<QUERY>`

Comment: Oh my.. How I didn't know that before? =p
Thank you very much, Colm =)

Comment: After the fact, but this donesn't work for me, just returns an empty data object.

Comment: Which permissions do I need for this job?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore, as facebook no longer allows event attendee requests without one of the event admins' access keys [(see Graph api reference)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending/). As they also [removed the option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640306/what-is-the-replacement-for-friends-events-permission-in-fb-graph-api-v2-0) to access friends' events for privacy reasons, there is currently no way of doing this solely via the Graph API